# Prove by induction of recursive sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

My classmates and I were working on this question on our discrete mathematics homework, but we can't figure it out. We are asked to consider the following recurrence:

\begin{equation*}
G_0 = 0; G_1 = 1; \\
G_n = 7G_{n-1} - 12G_{n-2}
\end{equation*}

for $n \geq 2$.

We have to prove that $G_n = 4^n - 3^n$.

Now, I know that this has to be done by some sort of strong induction. The way I'm approaching it right now is that I have two base cases, $n = 2$ and $n = 3$. After proving that those base cases work, I assume that the hypothesis holds true for some $n$ and $n+1$. Then I try to prove that it holds true for $n+2$, but I'm running into some trouble doing that. If I could get some guidance for this problem that would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need strong induction? I guess it depends on what you mean by "strong induction." Just show the base cases $0$ and $1$ and then prove the inductive step.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you need to assume that the result holds for at least the two previous cases otherwise you won't be able to use the inductive hypothesis on both terms.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that this is true for every $k\leq n+1$, For $n+2$ you have $G_{n+2}=7G_{n+1}-12G_n=7(4^{n+1}-3^{n+1})-12(4^n-3^n)$. So

$$G_{n+2}=7\cdot 4^{n+1}-3\cdot 4^{n+1}-7\cdot 3^{n+1}+4\cdot 3^{n+1}=4^{n+2}-3^{n+2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question about how you went from the first line to the second however. The first line is what I have, and I've been trying to simplify so I can get it equal to what's on the right side of the equation but I can't seem to do that. Could you clarify what steps you did to get to the second line? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $12\cdot  4^n=3\cdot 4\cdot 4^n=3\cdot 4^{n+1}$, the other calculus is the same this one. Change the term $-7\cdot 3^{n+1}$ by $12\cdot 4^n$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that your base cases are $n=0$ and $n=1$. The formula $G_n=4^n-3^n$ holds for all $n\ge0$. It is only the recurrence $G_n=7G_{n-1}-12G_{n-2}$ that is defined for all $n\ge2$ (since $G_0$ and $G_1$ were defined explicitly).

Once you have checked these two cases hold, then assume that the result holds for all $n\le k$ for some integer $k\ge 0$. Then when $n=k+1$ we have:

$$
\begin{split} G_{k+1}=7G_{k}-12G_{k-1} &= 7\cdot (4^{k}-3^{k})-12\cdot (4^{k-1}-3^{k-1}) \\ &= 7\cdot 4^k-12\cdot 4^{k-1}+12\cdot 3^{k-1}-7\cdot 3^{k} \\ &= 4^{k-1}\cdot (28-12)+3^{k-1}\cdot (12-21) \\ &= 4^{k-1}\cdot 16+3^{k-1}\cdot (-9) \\ &= 4^{k+1}-3^{k+1} \end{split}
$$

which is what we required. So the result holds for all $n\ge 0$ by induction.